# How toxic is brake fluid?

Tags: cleaning, brake-fluid, toxins

Is brake fluid especially toxic or is it about the same as dirty oil (not very toxic in trace amounts or just occasional human exposure).

I'm trying to figure out how much effort I should put in cleaning up a DOT 3 brake fluid spill that happened a year ago. Thank you for any help!

Comment: What DOT number is it? 3? Here's an MSDS https://www.lakeland.edu/PDFs/MSDS/287/Brake%20Fluid%20(All%20Brands).pdf

Comment: @Ben, nice link. So the answer to the question "How toxic is brake fluid" is - **not very** unless you drink a lot of it.

Comment: @Jimmy Haha, people cleaning up brake fluid around the world can rest assured, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most brake fluids are not terribly dangerous. Throw sand on it to absorb anything left, use a grease-cutting cleaner to get rid of the stain. You may wish to try brake cleaner and paper towels.

Comment: Since brake fluid is water soluble, lots of water could also clean it up. I asked a question about this (http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/28512/cleaning-brake-fluid-general-tips). But the additional techniques you mentioned could cut down on the amount of water needed?

Comment: @CarlGammaSagan Brake cleaner is my go-to stain remover for the garage floor :)